# linq change the value of a result set

Tags: c#, linq

C# - VS 2017 - LINQ to Entities
I need to pull some data, step through each of the items and if it meets a certain criteria change a flag.

**I know that it is because of the anonymous type -- I have read several posts about it but I don't know how to work around it.**

I need to change good from false to true.
Here is where I get the data:

```
var RMA_stops_all = (from rma in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                     join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on rma.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                     where line.RmaNumber != null
                         && (line.DatetimeCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma) 
                             && line.DatetimeCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma).AddDays(7))
                         && rma.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                     select new
                     {
                         line.DatetimeCreated,
                         rma.UniqueIdNo,
                         line.RmaNumber,
                         line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
                         line.ItemSequenceNo,
                         line.ItemNumber,
                         good = false
                     }).ToArray();
```

and here is where I step through each item:

```
foreach (var testRma in RMA_stops_all)
{
    if (testRma.RmaNumber.Contains("/078"))
    {
        testRma.good = true;
    }    
}
```

The error says:

> "Property or indexer 'anonymous type: DateTime? DatetimeCreated,
>   decimal UniqueIdNo, string RmaNumber, decimal? RmaOriginalUniqueId,
>   decimal ItemSequenceNo, string ItemNumber, bool good>.good' cannot be
>   assigned to -- it is read only"

Do I need to change my `LINQ` or my `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to change the anonymous object from:

```
select new
{
    line.DatetimeCreated,
    rma.UniqueIdNo,
    line.RmaNumber,
    line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
    line.ItemSequenceNo,
    line.ItemNumber,
    good = false
}
```

to:

```
select new
{
    dtCreated = line.DatetimeCreated,
    uniqueID = rma.UniqueIdNo,
    rmaNumber = line.RmaNumber,
    origUniqueID = line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
    itemSeqNo = line.ItemSequenceNo,
    item = line.ItemNumber,
    good = line.RmaNumber.Contains("/078")
}
```

I also named all of the variables inside the anonymous object, this will make accessing them easier should that be necessary later in the method.  It's a good habit to null check the value before the `Contains` call just in case, though I see you are doing so in the initial query.

Comment: That should be fine, though like I said, you're using the filter `where line.RmaNumber != null` in your query so won't be getting nulls anyway.  You can just leave that part out.

Comment: thank you...one more clarification -- any problem with me using the current field names - IE: UniqueIdNo = rma.UniqueIdNo  vs uniqueID  and RmaNumber vs rmaNumber?

Comment: Whatever names work for you, I am just in the habit of naming them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus of adding "Contains..." - much cleaner.

Comment: Note that anonymous types force you to have names for fields, and if the value is a simple field reference, it uses the same field name. I see no good reason to create new names or duplicate the names when creating the type.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous objects are read-only, once created they cannot be modified.

The solution to this problem is create a class for this, and add the needed properties in it, then use that class in the linq query to populate the collection of that type.

```
public class DataModel
{

  public DateTime DatetimeCreated {get;set;}
  ........................
  ........................
  // other properties that are needed
}
```

and then in your query project using that class:

```
select new DataModel {
    DateTimeCreated = line.DatetimeCreated,
    .............
    .............
    // other properties
}).ToArray();
```

Now you should be able to modify the collection down in the code.